# How to create a CSS button with horizontally split colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do [this button](https://www.canva.com/design/DAFKnGzyEpo/BeE0i1OhnY9IudYBDdY7NQ/view)

Do you have any advice on how to make that design of the button with the color split? I included the code I have done so far. Still need to change the font and a few other things.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    --antd-wave-shadow-color: #1890ff;
    --scroll-bar: 0;
    font-feature-settings: "tnum","tnum";
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    text-transform: none;
    font: 16px/1.4 Sen,sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5715;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
    user-select: none;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    outline: 0;
    border-color: #1890ff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.045);
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    padding: 6.4px 20px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 68px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #5675ff;
    font-family: RobotoBold3;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="button">BUY X </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to add 2 div inside the button tag.After that give different id or class to the created div and style them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leverage border radius instead of making complex calculations.

Here is a codepen sample that could give you a direction:

https://codepen.io/aSH-uncover/pen/VwXJgaj

the main trick here is

```
.button {
  border-radius: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and the usage of inner elements for your button

```
<button class="button">
  <div class='content top'>
    BUY $EVZ
  </div>
  <div class='content bottom'>
    POWERED BY DEPAY.CASH
  </div>
</button>
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic snippet. Play with the style of the button as much as you want.

```css
button .top{
  background: #5675ff;
  color:white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 20px
}
button .bottom{
  background:#ccc;
  padding: 5px 20px
}
button{
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  border-radius:15px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <div class="top">BUY X</div>
  <div class="bottom">I'm expensive!</div>
</button>
```